# Convergence of a subsequence in $(C(\mathbb{T}), \|\cdot\|_2)$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

*Problem:* Define, $ \mathbb{T} := \mathbb{R}/{2\pi\mathbb{Z}} $.
Consider a sequence of functions $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in C^4(\mathbb{T})$ such that, $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(\| g_n \|_2 + \| g'_n \|_2  + \| g''_n \|_2) < \infty $. Prove that $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence converging in $(C(\mathbb{T}), \|\cdot\|_2)$, where, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the norm,
$\|f\|_2 = (\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2dt)^{1/2}$.

*Background:* First course in analysis. This part of the course covers Fourier series, Fejér's theorem, covergence in the $L^\infty$ and $L^2$ norms. I know that the $C^4$ condition on the sequence of functions guarantees that the fourier series approximations of each function $g_n$ and its derivatives converge in both norms.

I don't really see how to approach the problem, unless there's some way to show that the space is compact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to prove compactness. This is an instance of [Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem), but presumably the point of the problem is to show compactness directly. To get uniform convergence, it suffices to have Fourier coefficients converging in $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$, so let's look at those.

Let $g_n^{(k)}$ be the $k$th coefficient of $g_n$. Then $g_n''$ has coefficients $-k^2 g_n^{(k)}$. So, the assumption that both $g_n$ and $g_n''$ are   bounded in $L^2$ norm implies the existence of a constant $M$ such that 
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(k^2+1)^2|g_n^{(k)}|^2\le M$$
Hence, $|g_n^{(k)}|\le M/(k^2+1)$. This is the main step of the proof: we got a summable *dominating sequence* $a_k=M/(k^2+1)$. For the rest, only this fact matters.

There are various ways to finish. One could use diagonalization to get coordinate-wise convergent subsequence and apply the dominated convergence theorem. Or one could prove the compactness of the set $A=\{c\in \ell^1: |c_k|\le a_k\ \forall k\}$ directly. Indeed, it is obviously closed in $\ell^1$, hence complete. To show total boundedness: given $\epsilon>0$, pick $N$ such that $\sum_{|k|>N}a_k<\epsilon/2$, and observe that $A$ is contained in the $\epsilon/2$-neighborhood of the set 
$$A_N=\{c\in \ell^1: |c_k|\le a_k\ \forall k,\text{ and } c_k=0 \text{ for }|k|>N\}$$
Since $A_N$ is compact, it admits a finite $\epsilon/2$ net. This net serves as an $\epsilon$-net of $A$.